# Modify link html with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

have this current dilemma, and would greatly appreciate your help.

Working on an eCommerce website, and would like to display a link to a size chart on the product page depending on the manufacturer.

My backend will automatically find and output the manufacturer as:

```
<div class="manufacturer">MANUFACTURER1</div>
```

and the size chart link as:

```
<a id="SizeChart1" href="http://www.mypartycentre.com/sizechart" target="_blank">Size Chart</a>
```

But what I would like to do is reference the manufacturer, and change the href in the size chart link for example:

```
<div class="manufacturer"> BRAND: REEBOK</div>
```

link to

```
<a id="SizeChart1" href="http://www.mypartycentre.com/REEBOK" target="_blank">Size Chart</a>
```

and if:

```
<div class="manufacturer"> BRAND: NIKE</div>
```

then show this link:

```
<a id="SizeChart2" href="http://www.mypartycentre.com/NIKE" target="_blank">Size Chart</a>
```

Again, appreciate your help

Comment: form where you will get your brand name? is it through `looping` or `array`??

Comment: why don't your backend displays the link too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define id for your div and try something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('DIV1').innerHTML;
if (MyDiv1== "REEBOK")//if it is  BRAND: REEBOK then check  BRAND: REEBOK
{
document.getElementById("SizeChart1").href="http://www.mypartycentre.com/REEBOK";
};
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9S5yW/